# Keep aspect ratio of window purely on ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Is it possible to preserve the aspect ratio of the window on WPF when getting resized? Right now, I want to base the aspect ratio from the height. Here is my code right now; the width and height changes doesn't take effect. Is it possible to achieve this by doing the changes purely on ViewModel? Is it possible to bind the Size Change event?

View Model Code:

```
private double _windowHeight = 650;
public double WindowHeight
{
    get { return _windowHeight; }
    set
    {
        _windowHeight = value;
        PreserveRatio();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowHeight));
    }
}

private double _windowWidth = 850;
public double WindowWidth
{
    get { return _windowWidth; }
    set
    {
        _windowWidth = value;
        PreserveRatio();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowWidth));
    }
}

private void PreserveRatio()
{
    double multiplier = (double)_widthRatio / (double)_heightRatio;
    var NewWidowWidth = WindowHeight * multiplier;
    if (WindowWidth != NewWidowWidth)
    {
        WindowWidth = NewWidowWidth;
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    x:Name="MainWindowView"
    Height="{Binding WindowHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Width="{Binding WindowWidth, Mode=TwoWay}">
</Window>
```

I followed how the linked duplicate solution done it, but it still doesn't work for me.

ViewModel Code:

```
private double _windowHeight = 650;
public double WindowHeight
{
    get { return _windowHeight; }
    set
    {
        _windowHeight = value;
        PreserveRatio();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowHeight));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WindowWidth));
    }
}

private double _windowWidth = 850;
public double WindowWidth
{
    get { return _windowWidth; }
    set
    {
        _windowWidth = value;
    }
}

private void PreserveRatio()
{
    double multiplier = (double)_widthRatio / (double)_heightRatio;
    var NewWidowWidth = WindowHeight * multiplier;
    if (WindowWidth != NewWidowWidth)
    {
        WindowWidth = NewWidowWidth;
    }
}
```

XAML code same as above

Codebehind:

```
protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
{
    if (sizeInfo.HeightChanged)
    {
        _vm.WindowHeight = sizeInfo.NewSize.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` on the Width and Height Binding has no effect. These properties do not change when you resize a Window.

Comment: @Clemens it triggers ang gets the value on the PreserveRatio method but once I set the new width it doesn't reflect or doesn't take effect.